# Generate Gene Plot for HG19 in R

Tags: r, plot

So, given a matrix from the HumanGenome19 project (hg19) I want to generate a plot in which I the genes and their strands will be plotted.

The data from `hg19` look like this:

```
GENE CHR txStart txEnd Size STRAND
RBBP8 chr18 2050000 42016610 113940 -
CCND3 chr18 41902670 42016610 113940 -
GGNBP1 chr18 33551475 33556803 5328 +
LINC00336 chr18 33553882 33561115 7233 -
PGM3 chr18 83874592 83903655 29063 -
PGM3 chr18 83874592 83903012 28420 -
PGM3 chr18 83874592 83903012 28420 -
```

`+` means that the gene will be plotted in the `right` direction, while - means `left`.

Do you know any R packages that can produce a plot like the following given `HG` data?

Also, I do not care about the position of the genes on the `Y-axis` they should be positioned so the name would be clear to read.

[image]

**Disclaimer**: the plot, does not respond to the data I've listed.

Comment: does the length of the arrow leans mean correspond to something? like gene size?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.tengfei.name/ggbio/ ... maybe Capter 7 of the vignette may give you a hint

Comment: @JustGettinStarted yes.

Comment: @Drey This is a general purpose library. It looks very good for other kinds of plots, but the specific one I want to accomplish.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggbio-visualize-genomic-data the second section shows a very similar plot like yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do it for your data because the range is very wide. I have made a similar looking plot for fake data using `arrows`. However, this may not work without further modification for you.

***DATA***

```
mydata = structure(list(GENE = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("CCND3", 
"GGNBP1", "LINC00336", "PGM3", "RBBP8"), class = "factor"), CHR = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "chr18", class = "factor"), 
    txStart = c(20500000L, 20780190L, 20982780L, 21218290L, 21533530L, 
    21851180L, 22073300L), txEnd = c(20557770L, 20806930L, 21140420L, 
    21299010L, 22513330L, 21863505L, 22162610L), Size = c(57770L, 
    26740L, 157640L, 80720L, 979800L, 12325L, 89310L), STRAND = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("-", "+"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("GENE", 
"CHR", "txStart", "txEnd", "Size", "STRAND"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

***CODE***

```
graphics.off()
windows(width = 10, height = 7)
plot(x = c(min(mydata$txStart), max(mydata$txEnd)), y = c(0,nrow(mydata)+1),
    type = "p", pch = NA, axes = FALSE, xlab = "Chromosome ## Mb", ylab = "")

# Divide range of genes into 4 groups to add ticks and labels in next step
x_label = seq(min(mydata$txStart),max(mydata$txEnd),(max(mydata$txEnd) - min(mydata$txStart))/4)

#add labels at 4 different places on x-axis
axis(1, at = x_label, labels = paste(as.character(round(x_label/1000000),2)," Mb",sep =""))

y_pos = 1 #Starting vertical position of genes
for (i in 1:nrow(mydata)){
    #use arrows from txStart to txEnd. Based on STRAND value, this may have to change with if else
    arrows(x0 = mydata$txStart[i], x1 = mydata$txEnd[i], y0 = y_pos, y1 = y_pos, length = 0.05)

    #Obtain x position to put gene label
    x_pos = mydata$txStart[i] + (mydata$txEnd[i] - mydata$txStart[i])/2
    gene_label = paste(mydata$GENE[i])

    #Add gene label
    text(x_pos, y_pos, bquote(italic(.(gene_label))), pos = 3, col = "darkgrey", cex = 0.8)
    y_pos = y_pos + 1 #Comment this if you want all genes on the same level
}
```

***PLOT***
[image]